# ant build missing jar from lib

Tags: java, ant, weblogic

I have a build.xml and I have a path for the classpath that I set to `classpathref="compile.classpath"` during compile:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="./lib">
        <include name="*" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

The lib folder contains `weblogic.jar` but when i try to compile the project, i got many errors because of missing the `weblogic.jar`

If I modify my path to this:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="./lib">
        <include name="*" />
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${env.WL_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib">
        <include name="weblogic.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

So I add the `weblogic.jar` from my local installed weblogic directory, there are no errors, and it's compiled.

I copied the `weblogic.jar` to my project lib folder from the local installed weblogic folder, so it must be the same `weblogic.jar`

What should I try? Thank you!

Comment: Can you check your env variables. WL_HOME should already be set to .../wl_server. So, your path should be ${env.BEA_HOME}/wl_server/server/lib

Comment: sorry, its working if i add my env.WL_HOME to the build file. its only not working when i add the weblogic.jar directly to the lib folder..

Comment: Are you using WebLogic 12c ? if so, the weblogic.jar is a manifest-only jar file : classes ARE NOT in the jar. The jar is "just" a link to other jars where classes are.

Comment: yes im using 12c. So i think it could be the problem. So when i inlcude, the weblogic.jar from the WL_HOME it can reach the other jars but when i add the weblogic.jar directly to the project lib folder it can't! can you tell me where can i get a NOT manifest-only weblogic.jar?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this in your build.xml (probably just before you do the compilation will work).

```
<property name="echo.classpath" refid="compile.classpath"/>
<echo message="compileClasspath - ${echo.classpath}"/>
```

What you probably need to do is to be quite explicit about where your lib directory is, relative paths are tricky if you have multiple build.xml files, and nested directories and stuff.

What I have done before is to make sure that you explicitly define a property in the right place for your lib directory, and just use that rather than `./`

```
<project basedir=".">
  <target name="init">
    <property name="local.lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib">
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <path id="compile.classpath">
      <fileset dir="${local.lib.dir}">
        <include name="*" />
      </fileset>
    </path>
    ....
  </target>
</project>
```